# Clustering by pair of 3 points for a given x position?

Tags: r

If I have a set of points that have different y positions (A,B,C) each with the same x coordinate. Is it possible to cluster this set of 3 points together and not individually?

I'd like to see the occurrence of this set of 3 points together in a given sample and see what set (A,B,C) is most frequent.

I've seen most of the clustering algorithm can cluster points for a given position (x,y) but not a set of several points for a given x coordinate.

For instance, if i have the following

```
X               A                 B               C
1               0.7               0.1             0.2
2               0.3               0.4             0.1
3               0.4               0.5             0.1
4               0.7               0.1             0.2
5               0.7               0.1             0.2
6               0.2               0.1             0.5
```

The positions x :1, 4 and 5 should be clustered together because they have the same set (A,B,C) = (0.7,0.1,0.2).

Is there any algorithm or tool (R) that is already doing that, clustering by pair of several points, finding the most occurrent pair with a graphical visualization?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: I have just edited my post with an example. Thanks.

Comment: In the first sentence, do you mean the same y positions but different x coordinates?

Comment: No Aaron, I mean same x position (x coordinate is the number of my sample) with different y positions (A, B, C which represent 3 different percentages for a given sample). Thanks.

Comment: Aside from the risks associated with floating-point values, perhaps `duplicated` or `aggregate` will help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Will this two functions work for a non-discrete value?

Comment: Please do not edit the title to indicate your problem is solved; that's what accepting an answer is for. (Also, I edited your terminology. It's extremely confusing to refer to a set of three things as a "pair". A "pair" always refers to exactly 2 things.)

Comment: Hi Joran, thanks a lot for all the correction. My bad for all the mistakes, i'm french :/ Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to see you have an answer.  I'm still confused though because it looks the answer is counting instances with the same y (ABC) but different x's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to tabulate the instances, then something along the lines of:

```
tab <- table(sprintf("%s:%s:%s", df1$A, df1$B, df1$C))
which.max(tab)
sort(tab, decreasing=TRUE)
```

will give you the most frequent combination (you can use `strsplit` to separate out the individual components if you need to go on and use them programmatically.

If you're looking to cluster, in the sense of find similar distances, then you can just use

```
dis <- dist(as.matrix(df1[[c("A","B","C")]])
clust <- hclust(dis)
```

and `dis` will tell you all the pairwise distances (find the zero's to get the identicals), and clust will give you a tree based on similarity across A:c

If this isn't answering the question, you probably need to clarify.  You say things like *same x coordinate* in the text, but none of your rows have the same *X* value.  And it's fairly unconventional to switch interchangeably between *y coordinate* / *position* / *(A,B,C)*  .

It's hard to suggest a visualisation without knowing what feature you want to emphasize.  Possibly a multi-dimensional scaling graph, where each node represents all x with the same (A,B,C) triplet, and then neighbours are other X's with closest (A', B', C') values?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for all this explanation. I'm sorry I haven't been clear about the coordinates. I meant that for a specific x position, a pair of 3 points (A, B, C) need to be considered together and not separately. Each x position is unique but at the end, several x position will have the same pair (A, B, C) and this is what i'd like to see, ie the most frequent pair (A,B,C). I think the functions you gave is suitable for this? Does it accept a file as parameter?

Comment: As for the graph, yes i'd like to represent the number of x that have a same specific pair, the most frequent pair but also the x that haven't the same pair but very close (A,B,C) values. Would the cluster  be suitable for this purpose? Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: OK, think I was along the correct track, then.  You'll need to read the data into a data.frame, using `read.table` or `read.csv`.  The object we generate, called `clust` will easily generate a tree, if you call `plot(clust)`, and the lowest leaves of the tree will be the identical `x`s.

Comment: Gavin, you're a star :) I'll give it a try now. Really thank you, you've been a huge help. Greeting from France.

Comment: The 1st part gave me an error because of the type of my values (double):
> tab <- read.table("C:/Users/emi/Desktop/Res.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
> which.max(tab)
Error in which.max(tab) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: You need to read your file into another variable (I called it `df1` in my example) and then use `tab <- table(df1...` to get the tabulation.  Looks like you've missed a step out

Comment: I put the columns while reading the file as following:
> tab <- read.table("C:/Users/emi/Desktop/Res.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t", col.names = c('A','B','C'))

Then:
tabPair <- table(sprintf("%s:%s:%s", df1$A, df1$B, df1$C))

But it says: object 'df1' not found

What does the df1 correspond to please? cheers.

Comment: The 1st part is working great, thank you.
As for the cluster, when i do this:
> dis <- dist(as.matrix(tab[[c("A","B","C")]]))
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : 
  recursive indexing failed at level 2

Comment: Gavin, i have a last question. You gave me a function that allows to find the most frequent combination. But does it respect the order of the column A, B, C? I mean is 1:0:0 and 0:0:1 and 0:1:0 considered as the same combination?

Comment: It treats them as different, and does respect the ordering of the columns.  If you want the other behaviour `srtd <- apply(df1[c("A","B","C"), 1, sort); tab <- table(sprintf("%s:%s:%s", srtd[1,], srtd[2,], srtd[3,]))`

Comment: Oh ok cool thank you, no I actually needed the different combinations to be different and respect the order of the columns so I'll use your 1st method. Do you have any idea why the dist function gives this error: Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : recursive indexing failed at level 2

Comment: Sorry, should be single `[ ]` rather than double `[[ ]]`  - if that doesn't fix it, check the names of your data.frame match the columns you're attempting to extract

Comment: Thank you. I've changed it but because i have a million row, it says the following:
 dis <- dist(as.matrix(df1[c("A","B","C")]))
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 5718.8 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In dist(as.matrix(df1[c("A", "B", "C")])) :
  Reached total allocation of 5921Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In dist(as.matrix(df1[c("A", "B", "C")])) :
  Reached total allocation of 5921Mb: see help(memory.size)

Comment: You're comparing every row to every other row, so you're going to have roughly the square of the number of rows comparisons - you'll either need a bigger machine, or rethink whether you need all distances.

Comment: But is 5718 GB really what i need to build the vector? That's impossible for any machine to have so much memory, no? Does the kmean algorithm build distances the same way?